# Change TabItem.Header, when selected, from image to text

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have bumped into a problem to which I am seeking the solution.
I have a tabControl with styles added to it.

I want to display only images on each TabItem.Header and when that tab is selected then hide the image from header and display text (the other, inactive headers will be showing images).

Can anybody provide any help?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid Name="Borderer" Background="#FF777777" Height="70" Width="90">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentTabItem" ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Borderer" Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />

                            <Setter Property="Header" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Tag" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="189" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="94,123,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500">
        <TabItem Name="tabItem1" IsSelected="True" >
            <TabItem.Tag>
                <TextBlock Text="blab lab la" />
            </TabItem.Tag>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Image Source="images/img1.png" Width="35" Height="35" />
            </TabItem.Header>

            <TabItem.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Name="aaa" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Tag>
                <TextBlock Text="la lab blab" />
            </TabItem.Tag>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Image Source="images/img2.png" Width="35" Height="35" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Name="bbb" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without replacing the whole ControlTemplate on the TabItem. You can just alter the TabItem's HeaderTemplate when the TabItem is selected, making your Style a lot shorter:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedHeaderTemplate" >
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}, 
                                      Path=Tag}" />
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedHeaderTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```